# After splitting i want to have condition on the length of the splitted string

Tags: c#

```
var myNew = myRegex1.Split(strTargetString);
                    if ((myNew[1].Trim()).Length > 12)
                    {
                       myNew[1]= (myNew[1].Substring(0, 9))+"..";
                    }                        }
                    _model.Add(new ScoresModel()
                    {
                        NameTeam1 = (myNew[1].Trim()),
                        ScoreTeam1 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[2].Trim()),
                        NameTeam2 = (myNew[3].Trim()),
                        ScoreTeam2 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[4].Trim()),
                        Round = (myNew[5].Trim()).Substring(1, myNew[5].Length - 2),
                        URL = item.ItemLink
                    });
```

Here above is my specification. after splitting the string into 5 parts. i want to apply a check on the first splitted string whether its length is greater than 12. If it is, then to trim it to 10 characters and append ".." (two dots) behind string.
* But after trimming code it is giving error in below method on myNew[1], myNew[2], myNew[3], myNew[4], myNew[5]. 
* Error is `The name myNew does not exist in current context.`

```
_model.Add(new ScoresModel()
                    {
                        NameTeam1 = (myNew[1].Trim()),
                        ScoreTeam1 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[2].Trim()),
                        NameTeam2 = (myNew[3].Trim()),
                        ScoreTeam2 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[4].Trim()),
                        Round = (myNew[5].Trim()).Substring(1, myNew[5].Length - 2),
                        URL = item.ItemLink
                    });
```

Comment: Not an answer, but, remember that array indexes start at zero. So if your regex splits the string in 5 parts the index start at zero and  end at four.

Comment: I'm just curious: what do you think the purpose of the surrounding parentheses is? i.e. `(myNew[1].Trim())`. There also seems to be a stray scoping brace; perhaps we're missing significant context for a more thorough answer than "your variable does not exist."

Comment: my code works with array indices from 1 to 5. Error only occurs when  if statement block is used before it.

Comment: @DollyJain so, you say that your array starts from index `1`, and all works if you comment out four lines of `if` condition?

Comment: are you sure your index start from 1 and not from 0?Also, I think that your myNew[1].Substring(0, 9) should be myNew[1].Substring(0, 10)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
var myNew = myRegex1.Split(strTargetString);
                    if ((myNew[0].Trim()).Length > 12)
                    {
                       myNew[0]= myNew[0].Substring(0, 10)+"..";
                    }   
_model.Add(new ScoresModel()
                    {
                        NameTeam1 = (myNew[0].Trim()),
                        ScoreTeam1 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[1].Trim()),
                        NameTeam2 = (myNew[2].Trim()),
                        ScoreTeam2 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[3].Trim()),
                        Round = (myNew[4].Trim()).Substring(1, myNew[4].Length - 2),
                        URL = item.ItemLink
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var myNew = myRegex1.Split(strTargetString);
_model.Add(new ScoresModel()
{
    NameTeam1 = myNew[0].Trim().Length > 12 ? myNew[0].Trim().Substring(0, 9)+".." : myNew[0].Trim(),
    ScoreTeam1 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[1].Trim()),
    NameTeam2 = myNew[2].Trim(),
    ScoreTeam2 = Convert.ToInt32(myNew[3].Trim()),
    Round = myNew[4].Trim().Substring(1, myNew[4].Trim().Length - 2),
    URL = item.ItemLink
});
```

The split result is 0-indexed ;) like this, you don't set the first element of the array, just use it.

Be careful when you test your string with Trim, if you don't use it later (for substring), you may have a error if string begin with space..